# const char* as argument to template

Tags: c++, templates

```
/* Find an item in an array-like object
 * @param val the val to search for
 * @param arr an array-like object in which to search for the given value
 * @param size the size of the array-like object
 * @return the index of the val in the array if successful, -1 otherwise
 */
template < class T>
int mybsearch(T val, T const arr[], const int &size)
```

When I try to call this template function using const char* and an array of strings, the compiler complains...`mybsearch("peaches", svals, slen)`, how could I modify the template prototype to accommodate this?

Here is the array of strings

```
  string svals[] = { "hello", "goodbye", "Apple", "pumpkin", "peaches" };
  const int slen = sizeof(svals)/sizeof(string);
```

Comment: What does the compiler complain about? Please post the error messages.

Comment: And the error message is... ?

Answer (score 2):

Because `T` is deduced as `const char*`, you are trying to initialize `const char* const[]` with a `string[]`. This is not gonna work (arrays can be only passed to function if the argument type is basically the same - save for qualifiers - as the parameter type).

You can either

- use C strings consistently, eg.:

  ```
  const char* svals[] = { "hello", "goodbye", "Apple", "pumpkin", "peaches" };
  ```

  *not* recommended.
- use C++ strings consistently

  ```
  mybsearch(string("peaches"), svals, slen)
  ```
- decouple the arguments to mybsearch (so you could search for elements of types different from the array type, as long as they're comparable)

  ```
  template < class T, class U>
  int mybsearch(T val, U const arr[], const int &size)
  ```

Comment: There's a 4th option: specify the type for `T` explicitly as `string` at call time: `mybsearch<string>("peaches", svals, slen)`. The complier will automatically convert `"peaches"` to a `string` using the appropriate constructor. Note, however, that specifying `T` to be a `const char*` won't work, as there's no implicit conversion from `string` to `const char *`, let alone for arrays of strings.

Comment: I have tried to decouple the arguments by passing an array as reference like 'U & arr'. I also try to cast the type of the items in arr to the type of T like 'T temp = (T) arr[0]', now what I am trying to do is to convert 'const char *' to string.

Answer (score 0):

*(Completely changed answer after the question got extended)*

The problem is that the value you search for is a `const char *`, but the array you search in is an array of `std::string`s.  (Well, I hope that you have `using std` somewhere up the code, and that you are using standard strings rather than your own.)

You need to invoke it like this:

mybsearch(string("peaches"), svals, slen)

Comment: How about this now? It seems that the compiler complains about the const char* doesn't match the string type

Comment: That is wrong; there are no constant reference types in C++, and `const`, when placed in the middle of a type, applies to the thing standing to its left.

Comment: @jpalecek Oops, you're right, I mixed this up with `char & const`.  Will edit or delete.  Thanks.

Comment: The template is correct after all, but the invocation is not.